# Is there something similar to ionViewDidLoad in angular material?

Tags: ionic-framework, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to use < canvas > elements in my angular material code. Usually with ionic, I fill my typescript to draw actual information of those canvases inside ionViewDidLoad(). But I'm not sure how to draw these canvases in angular material. Is there an alternative similar to ionViewDidLoad() in angular-material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides some lifecycle hooks out of the box. Perhaps you can use [onInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) which is very similar to `ionViewDidLoad`. The Angular lifecycle hooks are available as long as you're using Angular 2 or higher.

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

    // implement OnInit's `ngOnInit` method
    ngOnInit() { 
        console.log('component inited'); 
    }

}
```

Note that you have to implement the OnInit (as opposed to simply adding the method your component in Ionic)